# Do you need to have a physical copy of Pokemon White 1 to link it to White 2?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I **had** Pokemon White but I lost it somehow.  I was wondering if I still needed it to link it to Pokemon White 2 and get story related things.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can play Pokemon White 2 without Pokemon White, as any other game of the series.

The game takes place two years after the events of Pokémon Black and White, it's just a sequel.